# Incompatible receiver when getting a proxy of a Map from a getter

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with the following piece of code:

```js
class Infrastructure {
  constructor () {
    this._devices = new Map([
     ['foo', 'bar']
    ])
  }
  
  get devices () {
    return new Proxy(this._devices, {})
  }
}

const infrastructure = new Infrastructure()
console.log(infrastructure.devices.get('foo'))
```

Which fails with the following error:

> Method Map.prototype.get called on incompatible receiver

I know I need to bind something somewhere, but I have to admit I am kind of lost.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sreekanth it's not *my* Proxy class, it's the [ES2015 proxy](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#proxies)

Comment: `infrastructure.devices.get('foo')` what do expect this return ?

Comment: It should return `bar`. See [Map](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#map-set-weak-map-weak-set)

Answer (score 1):

This would solve the problem.  Will update once I have a concrete explanation.

```js
class Infrastructure {
  constructor() {
    this._devices = new Map([
      ['foo', 'bar']
    ])
  }

  get devices() {
    return new Proxy(this._devices, {})
  }
};

const infrastructure = new Infrastructure()
console.log(infrastructure.devices.get.bind(infrastructure._devices)('foo'))
```

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the idea of binding to an internal "private" property. There's probably a way to have a natural API (just like a raw Map object) through a Proxy... And I don't only want to access `get()`, but also the whole `Map` methods.